# paypalのAPIのパラメータmerchant-generated-ID

Tags: api, paypal

paypalのAPIを使った処理を作成しています。
ドキュメントを見ながら進めていますが、途中に出てくるmerchant-generated-IDというのが何を指しているのかが分かりません。
（URLとキャプチャを添付します）

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#1-create-a-product

詳しい方いましたら教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/193588